# Fallo .htaccess en XAMPP

Tags: xampp, .htaccess

Estoy intentado hacer un .htaccess para que no se muestren las extensiones ".html" y ".php" en mi instalación XAMPP en local. El caso es que parece que no está funcionando ya que cuando hago entro a un enlace (ejemplo:entrar en "pagina1.php" con solo "pagina2") me lleva a la página de error.
He cambiado en el archivo "xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf":

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

a

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

y

```
AllowOverride None
```

a

```
AllowOverride All
```

Después he reiniciado el servidor XAMPP.

Este es mi .htaccess que he colocado en la carpeta del sitio:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

¿Alguién me puede decir por qué no funciona?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este código jamás me ha fallado para quitar las extensiones

```
# Quitar extensión de las URL
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
# END Quitar extensión de las URL
```

Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada si solventa tu duda.

Comment: Hola, mi problema es que .htaccess no funciona en XAMPP. El .htaccess en si mismo, si funciona. Lo he comprobado en otro servidor. Pero en XAMPP nada. Me interesa saber por que no está funcionando ya que las pruebas las estoy haciendo en local y de este modo esto me entorpece.

Comment: Yo uso XAMPP con ese **.hataccess** desde siempre.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón. Acabo de probar tu htaccess y funciona correctamente en XAMPP. La verdad no entiendo por que el mío no funcionaba también en XAMPP ya que como comenté iba bien en el otro servidor real. Supongo que había algo mal escrito. Mil gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Ojo, no es exclusivo de XAMPP, funciona en todos los sitios y sistemas que tengo subidos en varios hosting de varios países. Solo lo aclaro para que no venga alguien con WAMP o LAMP o cualquier hosting y piense que esto es para XAMPP...